# Detect beacon using older version then Android 4.3

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I made a beacon's app and i would like to adapt it for android 4.1 (API 16).
Beacons use BLE but it's implemented for version 4.3+.
Is it possible to use classic bluetooth to detect them?

```
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager', referenced from method org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.checkAvailability
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk$2', referenced from method com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk.getObservable
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk$1', referenced from method com.orhanobut.hawk.Hawk.putObservable
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.orhanobut.hawk.HawkBuilder$2', referenced from method com.orhanobut.hawk.HawkBuilder.buildRx
```

Comment: Short Answer: No, BLE != Bluetooth.

Comment: ok then I keep minSdkVersion 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Beacons work only with Bluetooth LE**, not Bluetooth Classic.  And Bluetooth LE detection generally **requires Android 4.3+**.

The only exception to that is on certain Samsung devices with a stock ROM running 4.2.x.  Samsung built their own Bluetooth LE stack with their own APIs.  [A branch of the Android Beacon Library](https://github.com/davidgyoung/android-beacon-library/tree/samsung-ble-sdk) added support for these devices.